# Tree structure with XTS and HMAC: MAC in parent

Tags: hmac, hash-tree, xts

Situation:
A file format contains a tree-like data structure; parent nodes can find children and child nodes can also find their (single) parent. To protect confidentiality, the nodes in the file are encrypted with AES-XTS (one node may be more than one AES block, ie. more than 16 bytes). For authenticity, a HMAC is used on the encrypted nodes (ie. "encrypt-then-MAC").

What are the advantages/disadvantages between
a) Storing the MAC togther with the node
b) Storing the MAC in the parent node plaintext (MAC together with parent   plaintext is then encrypted and MACed again as part of the parent).

For A, I can think at least of an attacker observing changes to the file, and then changing a whole node back to an old state - as the MAC is changed back too, it won't be recognized. With B, either the whole file or nothing can be rolled back like that, just parts of the file won't work. (If the authenticity of the top node can be protected in some other way, the problem is solved completely).

So, B sounds much better - but are there other problems that A won't have? (And, are there some huge problems for confid./authent. that I have overlooked in both methods?)

Comment: Why are you using XTS?  The only reason you would use XTS, rather than a more standard mode, is that you cannot handle any ciphertext expansion (which is usually the case for encrypting disk blocks).  In your case, you have space for a MAC; hence you can use a more conventional mode, and include space for an IV/nonce...

Comment: May be - but still it would be great to get an answer for the XTS situation (and in case B, which currently sounds better, there is no space needed outside of nodes anyways)

Comment: The only problem I see with the B solution is that you cannot verify the authenticity without also retrieving the parent. And you can extend A by performing a single hash over the MAC data and store that in the parent. Just some food for thought...

Comment: One obvious downside of option B is that modifying a node will require updating all of its parents as well. Of course, that's kind of unavoidable if you want the improved integrity protection offered by option B. BTW, you could also consider using an [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) mode and treating the auth tokens (MACs) of the child notes as associated data for the parents.

Comment: The problem with answering this question is that there are many possibilities here, which can be all cryptographically sound. I'll vote this question as primarily opinion based as I don't see an requirements that can distinguish one good option from another (hoping that - in the mean time - our comments have helped you on your way).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you, they did. And I would like to make my question more clear, but I have no idea what kind of differences you mean, what more is required to know if it is sound